# Excel data validation reference spreadsheet location versus static list

Tags: validation, excel, vba

I'm having trouble with some Excel data validation. On one sheet, I have a list of values that contain the list that populates the validation drop-down, like this:

```
A1 |1.)   New Item
A2 |2.)  Miscellaneous
A3 |3.)  Change Order
A4 |4.)  Choose the item being broken out:
A5 |          Caulk NP-1
A6 |          Safety signs
A7 |          Warning lines
A8 |          Snow fence
A9 |          Drain Lead 4 lb 30"x30" 
A10 |          Cant Strip
A11 |          Screws 1 5/8" 
A12 |          SS Sheet Metal 24 gauge
A13 |          Sheet Metal Aluminum 040 mill finish 
A14 |          Sheet Metal Aluminum .050 mill finish
A15 |          Termination Bar
A16 |          Lead Boots 2"
A17 |          Lead Boots 3" 
A18 |          Modified Bitumen Smooth APP
A19 |          TREMCO ELS Mastic
A20 |          TREMCO Polyroof SF
A21 |          TREMCO Base sheet fasteners
A22 |          TREMCO BURmastic Composite
A23 |          TREMCO PowerPly Standard
A24 |          TREMCO BURmastic SF
A25 |          TREMCO PowerPly HD Base Sheet
A26 |          TREMCO PowerPly Standard FR
A27 |          TREMCO Burmesh 6"
A28 |          TREMCO Site visits
A29 |          TREMCO Reglet Sealant
A30 |          TREMCO WB Primer
A31 |          TREMCO Ice Coating
A32 |          TREMCO Tremflash tape
A33 |          TREMCO Warranty
A34 |          1/4" x 1 1/2" drive pins
A35 |          SS Roof Nails 1 1/4"
A36 |          Freight
A37 |          Auto Fuel
A38 |          PA Direct Labor Supervisor
A39 |          PA Direct Labor Sheet Metal
A40 |          PA Direct Labor Roof Coating
A41 |          Equipment Crane 45 ton
A42 |          Equipment Crane 70 ton
A43 |          Platform Hoist R&G 400 28'
A44 |          Sqeegies 24" Notched
A45 |          Dumpsters
A46 |          Porta John
A47 |          Permit
A48 |          Subcontractor RK Hydro Vac 
A49 |          Subcontractor Roofing ICG
A50 |          Subcontractor Lightning Protection
A51 |          Misc
A52 |          Subtotal
```

When I have another sheet reference this list, the validation works properly. However, I have a VBA macro that at some point copies this other sheet into a workbook by itself to be emailed. For this and other reasons, I need the validation drop-down list on this column to not be dependent on the other sheet, so I have the macro loop through all of the cells and create a validation string that looks like this:

```
  1.)   New Item,2.)  Miscellaneous,3.)  Change Order,4.)  Choose the item being broken
 out:,          Caulk NP-1 ,          Safety signs,         Warning lines
```

As you can see, it's the exact same list, but it's a text string, with each selection separated by commas. It works almost like I need it to, but there is a problem - The 10 leading spaces are not working like they should in the second scenario. I have them there so that those selections are indented in the drop-down box to make it more intuitive. The 10 leading spaces are in the actual "validation list formula", but don't show up when I click the drop-down or make a selection!

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
As requested, here's the actual code:

```
Range("A1").Value = "1.)   New Item"
Range("A2").Value = "2.)  Miscellaneous"
Range("A3").Value = "3.)  Change Order"
Range("A4").Value = "4.)  Choose the item being broken out:"
Range("A5:A350").Formula = "=""          ""&INDIRECT(""'Buy Out'!B""&MATCH(""Description"",'Buy Out'!$B:$B,0)+ROW()-3)"
Application.Calculate

' build ValidationList string for later use (this will also have to happen when misc section isn't built, so this isn't the best place for it)
Range("A1").Select
ValidationList = ActiveCell.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Row = 350
    If ActiveCell.Value = "          Subtotal" Or ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Value = "          Subtotals" Then 'end of the loop
        Exit Do
    End If

    If ActiveCell.Value <> "" Then
        ValidationList = ValidationList & "," & vbTab & ActiveCell.Value
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    If ActiveCell.Row = 349 Then 'this shouldn't ever happen
        ValidationListMessedUp = True
        'MsgBox ("There appears to be a problem creating the drop-down list for the ""Addon Category/Item to Break Out"".")
    End If
Loop


'back to buy out and populate validation as dynamic formula
Sheets("Buy Out").Select
Cells.Find(What:="Addon Category/Item to Break Out", after:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate '* EH and message? "Is this job on the most recent MBO template? It does not appear to have the words "Release #" anywhere on the Buy Out tab

With Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(TotalRow - ActiveCell.Row - 2, 0)).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:= _
        "=INDIRECT(""reference!$A$1:$A$""&IFERROR(MATCH(""          Subtotal"",reference!$A:$A,0)-1,IFERROR(MATCH(""          Grand Total"",reference!$A:$A,0)-1,MATCH(""          Subtotals"",reference!$A:$A,0)-3)))"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

So the last section of this code that fills the validation with the indirect formula is the one that is working properly. Later on in the code, I populate the "static" validation list using the string. Here is that other piece:

```
    With Range(ActiveCell.Offset(MiscStartRow - ActiveCell.Row + 1, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(TotalRow - ActiveCell.Row + 5, 0)).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=ValidationList
    .IgnoreBlank = False
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Thanks so much for the help. This is getting really frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `vbTab`

For example

```
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="1,2,3," & vbTab & "          4,5"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Hope this is what you wanted?

**FOLLOW UP**

Using the above method has a drawback. DVlist cannot be more than 255 Characters.

**ALTERNATIVE**

Copy the list to extreme left column (*Column XFD (excel 2007/2010) or Column IV (Excel 2003)*) of the worksheet so that it is hidden and then use it in DV

Comment: okay, so at first that worked, but after further review, it is not. While Excel is still open, it seems to be working correctly. However, if I try to save the file and then re-open Excel, is says there are errors in the file that it must repair. When it repairs, it says it repaired the validation, and in fact has removed it...

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue. The file works just fine even after I close it and open it again. Can you share the exact code that you are using?

Comment: okay, I will edit the original question to include the code and the full item list populating the drop-down

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code ;) It is the data. Your data has quotes (" ") so when you are concatenating the string, even the quotes are getting concatenated which is giving you the error. let me see If I can do something about it :)

Comment: oooooooh. wow. How about the Substitute function to replace all quotes with 2 quotes?

Comment: So do you want to check for a solution or are you removing the double quotes?

Comment: Sorry if my comments were confusing. If you can come up with a way to keep the quotes, that would be great.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9107/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-carmalize)